# How to post my page back to itself?

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I have a list that I need to process 1 at a time. The list is too long for a querystring for me to just redirect back to my same page with 1 of the items "processed" and taken off the list.
What code can I do to post my form back to itself after I put my list value into a hidden input?

The reason I need to redirect is because I am using Telerik ExportToExcel() from a gridview, and it will cause a download to open up. My purpose is to save the stream into a file (I was able to do this) and then redirect so that I can do the next one in the list.

Comment: How many items in your list?  And the user is going to have to click Open or Save for every item in that list?

Comment: hi, the list is 1-1000s of entrys they may pick from a checkbox listing. they wont see anything happening until the full operation is completed most likely. after they are all done and processed i will zip it up and give them a link to the zip. they will just be checking x amount of boxes and submit. then they get a final zip link.